# Django Admin: Add text at runtime next to a field

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a text next to a field of the django admin interface.

The warning needs to created at runtime inside a python method. I know python and the django ORM well, but I don't know how to get the text next the field.

The text should be a warning. Raising ValidationError in clean() is not a solution, since
the user can't edit the page any more. It should be just a warning message.

Comment: do you want add text in list shown in django admin? for example model.text value and some else text ?

Comment: I want the warning in change_form (on the edit model instance) page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use custom `ModelForm` subclass for the admin, adding `help_text` attribute for the field in question at its initialization, and style it appropriately.

```
# forms.py

class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_in_question'].help_text = generate_warning()

# admin.py

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.YourModelForm

    # And here you can specify custom CSS / JS which would make
    # `help_text` for that particular field look like a warning.
    # Or you can make it generic--say, style (and maybe reposition w/js) all tags
    # like <span class="warning"> that occur within the help text of any field.

    class Media:
        css = {"all": ("admin_warning.css", )}
        js = ("admin_warning.js", )
```

Comment: Thank you. I set a div with class errornote on the help_text and get what I want.

Comment: One underscore too much in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to override the specific admin page for that model. This is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) in the Django documentation. The template you need to override is probably `change_form.html`. Within these template displayed object is available in the template variable `original`.

I would add a method or property to you model, that generates and returns the error message and call this method from the template.

*Edit*: Have a look at `contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html` there is a include for `includes/fieldset.html` that displays the the fields of the admin site. You could put some code there that chckes if the model has some special named attribute and if so it is displayed. You could them simply override that `change_form.html` for all models with your custom one.

Comment: The part "next to the field" is important for me. It is quite easy to add some message at the top of the page with the solution you suggested. But I want to get the warning next to an input field. Moving it there with css+js is not a solution.

Comment: I can't find a block that I can override in 'includes/fieldset.html'. I don't want to copy the whole fieldset.html file, just to modify one line. I guess a own ModelAdminForm is betters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in changelist view, you can write in model method, which returns string in format you want, and put name of that method in list_display in admin.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def myfield_with_warning(self):
       return '%s - %s' % (self.myfield, '<span class="warn">My warning message</p>'
    myfield_with_warning.short_description = 'My field verbose name'
    myfield_with_warning.allow_tags = True

class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('myfield_with_warning',)
```

If it's not what you need, write more precisely, where do you want to display warning message.